# Joining two ordered arrays, randomly mingle items, but keep original order

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

To make one array by **randomly** scattering items of two ordered arrays, while in the new array A is still before B, p before q, etc.

How to do it?   I can use underscorejs or jquery.

```
[A,B,C,D]
[p,q,r,s]
==>
[p,q,A,r,B,C,D,s], or [A,B,p,C,q,r,s,D] or [A,p,q,B,r,C,s,D] or...

The following is not OK.
[B,p,A,...] or [p,A,r,...]
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Write something like a coin flip (array1 = 0 / array2 = 1) to decide which array to shift() from. Check arrays if anything is left. Wash. Rinse. Repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question contains the answer how to do it.

Take a random array.
Move the first element from it to the resulting array.
Repeat until all elements are moved.

One of possible solutions:

```js
var a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], b = ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'], c = [];

while (a.length||b.length) {
  var r = Math.random()+.5|0;
  c.push([a, b][r].shift()||[a, b][+!r].shift());
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(c))
```

Comment: Wow, your solution is so compact.

Comment: @KaFaiLo, thank you. I have a very bad memory and cannot keep long code in my brain. =))

Comment: It does quite often ""Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shift' of undefined"

Comment: I accept this answer though I don't understand what it says, eg single pipe `|`, and `[a, b][r]`.  It works anyway.  The answer I gave also works.   Actually I would like to know a generic way to do this for any number of arrays, but it is beyond the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla js in the end.

```
var cap = ['A','B','C','D'];
var small = ['p','q','r','s'];

var arr = [];
var length = cap.length + small.length;
for(var i=0; i<length; i++) {
    var rand = Math.random()-0.5;
    var cond = rand > 0;
    var pick;
    if ( cap.length == 0 ) { pick = small; }
    else if ( small.length == 0 ) { pick = cap; }
    else { pick = cond ? cap : small; }
    arr.push( pick.shift() );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With underscore, you can make use of [`sample`](https://underscorejs.org/#sample) for the general case (i.e. any number of arrays):

```js
function mix(...arrays) {
  var res = [];
  while (_.some(arrays, a => a.length)) {
    res.push(_.sample(_.filter(arrays, a => a.length)).shift());
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(mix(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['p', 'q', 'r', 's'], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```